# Assigning a video URL twice

Tags: javascript, html5-video

In a web app we use 2 x html5 video tags. One for a simple preview player within a media browser and the other one as the main player. In the media browser, which is a modal dialog, all you can do is choose a video. Once you confirm the dialog, the chosen video will be displayed in the main player to continue there. So all you need to do is to assign the url of the `previewPlayer.src` to the `mainPlayer.src` like this:

```
mainPlayer.src = previewPlayer.src
```

So far, so good. Better to say bad because assigning an url twice means the browser loads the video file twice. Is there a clever way to avoid that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "load" the video? If you mean download over the network, I'm pretty sure modern browsers will only download it once.

Comment: load means that the browser making requests to the server and in this case starts from the scratch even part of the video has been downloaded (buffered) already. I am not talking about "downloading" a video to a lokal disk for further use from there. I am talking about downloading a video for playing back in the browser which is the purpose of a html5 video tag. How do you call this process ?